# How to map a related table with no primary key with fluent-NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Looks a common situation to me: I have two tables:
documents:
dID (pk, int), dName(varchar)

and document_options:
dID (int), oType(int), oValue(varchar)

I would like to have a class Document with a property Options (a List of DocumentOption class)

Since document_options has no PK I cannot use HasMany, and rows from this table don't seem like 'real' entities anyway...

I see a way to generate an auto-number key for document options and map with HasMany, or maybe create a composite ID, but I'd like to know if there is a better option that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `DocumentOptions` is a value object, since it has no identity of its own and has no meaning outside of the document it belongs to. So, you would use `Component` to map the collection properties to the value object.

```
public class Document : Entity // don't worry about Entity; it's a base type I created that contains the Id property
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DocumentOptions> Options { get; protected set; }

    public Document()
    {
        Options = new List<DocumentOptions>();
    }
}

public class DocumentOptions
{
    public virtual int Type { get; set; }

    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
public DocumentMap()
{
    Table("documents");

    Id(c => c.Id)
        .Column("dId")
        .GeneratedBy.HiLo("10");

    Map(c => c.Name)
        .Column("dName");

    HasMany(c => c.Options)
        .Component(c =>
                       {
                           c.Map(c2 => c2.Value).Column("oValue");
                           c.Map(c2 => c2.Type).Column("oType");
                       })
        .Table("document_options")
        .KeyColumn("dId")
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, After a lot of reading I came up with a very similar answer, only it uses no Id and maybe some other trivialities =)

Comment: Indeed, there are a few similar methods. With the exception of forgetting to specify the table names, I was trying to get the mapping to match the tables exactly as you specified in your question.

Comment: Would you mind telling me why you use "protected set" and create a new list of options in the constructor also please? My solution seems to work but you seem to know more about it than me.

Comment: You don't have to, but I do this to prevent consumers of my API from getting a `NullReferenceException` in the event that they forget to initialize the collection before they use it. Furthermore, I am indicating to these consumers that `Options` is managed by the API, not by them, by using `protected set`; all they need to worry about is adding, removing, and/or enumerating the options if there are any. Again, this is not required, but a good practice that become a  habit for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I had to map options as a list of components:

```
HasMany(x => x.DocumentOptions)
    .Table("document_options")
    .KeyColumn("dID")
    .Component(c => {
            c.Map(x => x.Option, "oID");
            c.Map(x => x.Value, "oValue");
    })
    .Fetch.Subselect(); //This type of join isn't strictly needed, is used for SQL optimization
```

classes FYI:

```
public class Options {
    public virtual int Option { get; set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Document {
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<DocumentOption> DocumentOptions { get; set; }
}
```